# PHP; How to get string between delimiter and end of string?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string like this:

```
$string = "This is my name: David";
```

And I want to turn it into this:

```
This is my name: <a href="https://www.example.com?q=David">David</a>
```

Means:

Get everything between "name: " (first delimiter) and the end of the string (second delimiter).

Set `</a>` after the extracted string (in this case "David").

Set `<a href="https://www.example.com?q=">` in front of the extracted string (in this case "David").

Insert the extracted string (in this case "David") after "`q=`" like: `q=David`

I'm good in PHP but I always stuck with regular expressions.

Is the anybody who can help me to do this?

**EDIT:**

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$string = "This is my name: David";
if(stripos($string, "name: ") !== false) {
$string = str_replace("name: ", "<a href=\"https://www.example.com?q=\">", $string);
$string = implode(array($string, "</a>"));
}
echo $string;
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried any thing? Then post it here.

Comment: `$string = preg_replace('/\b(name:\h*)(\S+)/', '$1<a href="https://www.example.com?q=$2">$2</a>', $string);`

Comment: You definately don't need a regular expression for this.

Comment: combination of `strpos`, `substr` and `strlen` should suffice

Comment: @anubhava Hey anubhava, thank you very much, it's working. If you post this as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `preg_replace`:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\b(name:\h*)(.+)/i', 
  '$1<a href="https://www.example.com?q=$2">$2</a>', $string);
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Start with a word boundary
- `(name:\h*)`: Match `name:` followed by 0 ore more horizontal whitespaces characters in capture group #1
- `(.+)`: Match 1+ of any characters in capture group #2
- `/i`: Ignore case modifier
- In substitution we use `$1` and `$2` to get our formatted html

Comment: Thank you very much. If name has a space, e.g. "David Moore", only "David" will get linked. Not the entire string till the end of the string. The string "David Moore" should be after "q=" WITH space.

Comment: Working, great, thank you very much and have a great day, David.